# How to make a recursive rename operation (Linux, using python) reversible?

Tags: python, recursion, reverse

How to make a recursive rename operation (Linux, using python) reversible?

I want to write a program under Linux and using python, this program do this job: Batch recursive rename all file in a folder, if the filename have substring X, rename to Y, Example: rename markdown to md, github.markdown will be renam to github.md.

The tough part is how to make the operation reversible? If I want change filename back. Example: change github.md back to github.markdown.

How to design the program and keep simple, using what algorithm and data structure?

Answer (score 2):

> Save original filename and the renamed filename into a file, any better approaches?

I think this is the most robust approach. It will work even if the renaming is lossy (i.e. if you can't reconstruct the original filename or location just by looking at the renamed filename).

That said, since you're using Linux, why not just [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) the files to make them accessible under the other set of names? In Python, this can be done using [`os.symlink()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.symlink).

Comment: +1 for `symlink`ing. OP might benefit from an explanation of "how to symlink"

Comment: Thanks a lot, symlink is a new approach, I never thought about that before, the smart part is that it deliver the potential problem which caused by location or structure big change to operating system, OS will handle it for you, brilliant idea, it will take some time to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to reverse the whole operation if there is an error or exception.

I would use two possible approaches, depending on the case:

1) Using a LIFO Queue (class Queue.LifoQueue).

Do a put() to the LIFO Queue once every operation is completed.

If there is an error or exception, just get().

Some sample code:

```
import os, Queue.LifoQueue

stack = Queue.LifoQueue()
from = 'original.txt'
to = 'new.txt'
if os.system('mv %s %s' % (from, to)) == 0: # execute operation
    stack.put('mv %s %s' % (to, from)) # save reverse operation

os.system(stack.get()) # execute reverse operation
```

2) "Try before you buy"

If there is a way to simulate operations, then simulate them all, and if they work, execute them all, no need to reverse anything.

Comment: yeah, your assumption is right, if there is an error or exception, I want to reverse the whole operation. By the way, your solution is good, simple and clear, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a [revision control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). With that, all changes can be registered and undon. There are [many different programs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software) to choose from.

If your directory contains only text files, you could use the venerable [RCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_Control_System). Personally I'm quite fond of [git](http://git-scm.com/) because like RCS, the version information is contained in the directory that is under revision control. The advantage of git is that it can also handle binary files and can deal with moves and renames. Alternatives like [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System) and [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) generally require you to set up a repository.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Revision Control System is an option, it is a heavy "weapon", even the master - Linus make that kind of things much simpler and easier through create git, it still a heavy tools, heavy tools are powerful but complex, so unless I was dreadfully cornered, I would not to use RCS.